# I only have microsoft office, how can i write code to manipulate relational data sets?

Tags: python, dataset, data-cleaning, data, programming

At work, I am in a role that does not have a lot of computer permissions. I do have the Microsoft office suite. I have skills with programming and would like to be able to use my experience to do more streamlined and substantial manipulation of large relational data sets. Considering I can't get python or even Bash, is there any good way to do this?

Comment: If you have Excel, you have access to write VBA scripts

Comment: You can write SQL in Access

Comment: Have you tried power query using the data model in Excel

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to install Python without admin privileges. This has been discussed on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876657/how-to-install-python-any-version-in-windows-when-youve-no-admin-priviledges).

The easiest method appears to be installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux).

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301675/how-can-i-run-windows-bash-without-being-root) you should also be able to use WSL without admin rights, which will get you bash.

For handling relational data you can use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/), which is built-in to Python. For example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```